# How to use .NET Reflection in order to add new Event Handler - one small issue, non-standard approach is needed

Tags: .net, web-services, events, reflection, delegates

It was long time ago when i asked a question here last time :) Now it's time to ask again, as i no any ideas ho to implement what i need...

One important thing to note - i'm writing application for Windows Phone 7.5 and it equals to Silverlight 3.0, so some features you may suggest won't work there (like iClientMessageInspector is absent in SL 3.0/WP7.5 or i can't set private fields from some class by using reflection - it's important thing to mention).

Ok, my goal is to subscribe to every event of the generated web-service proxy class where event name ends with "Completed" and to understand does web-operation fail with Exception or not (so - goal is to have one place to process errors from all web-services in the project - e.g. user is not authenticated due to session end).

I have one class to create all web-service clients (in my project there are about 4 web-service references) so it can be useful to have just single method to handle all exceptions that appears in the web-service calls made by all web-service types. This class name is WebManager, and it contains properties (1 property for one web-service type) that creates web-service, like this:

```
    public SomeServiceReference.AuthenticationServiceClient AuthenticationService
    {
        get
        {
            var web = new SomeServiceReference.AuthenticationServiceClient();  
            // here i plan to subscribe to xxxCompleted event 
            // i'll provide final code below            
            return web;
        }
    }
```

in the generaged web-service proxy class (Reference.cs) i have several events and they fired every time when web-operation ends, all of them named in this pattern : "Web_service_OperationName" + "Completed", sample:

```
public event System.EventHandler<SomeOperationCompletedEventArgs> SomeOperationCompleted;
```

Another important thing to mention: SomeOperationCompletedEventArgs is inherited from standard System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs so in the WebManager class i can write some method and to use it as default event handler:

```
public void TestEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // analyze web-call results here: 
    // do we have exception or web-operation completed successfully
    // if (e.Error != null) { /*do something there*/  }
}
```

So i can do something like this, in order to subscribe to SomeOperationCompleted event and to understand does operation fail or not:

```
    public SomeServiceReference.AuthenticationServiceClient AuthenticationService
    {
        get
        {
            var web = new SomeServiceReference.AuthenticationServiceClient();  
            web.SomeOperationCompleted += TestEventHandler;          
            return web;
        }
    }
```

This approach works fine and if you place breakpoint in the TestEventHandler method you'll see operation details in the "e" parameter.

But it's not an optimal way to write all event subscriptions for the every event in the Reference.cs, so i'm trying to find a way how to automate it.

I tried to add new event handler for all events in the Reference.cs like this:

```
        public SomeServiceReference.AuthenticationServiceClient AuthenticationService
    {
        get
        {
            var web = new SomeServiceReference.AuthenticationServiceClient();
            var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            var type = web.GetType();
            var eventsCompleted = type.GetEvents(bindingFlags).Where(e => e.Name.EndsWith("Completed")).ToArray();
            var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("TestEventHandler");
            foreach (var eventInfo in eventsCompleted)
            {
                //Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this, methodInfo);
                Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(System.EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>), this, methodInfo);
                //eventInfo.AddEventHandler(this, handler);
                MethodInfo addHandler = eventInfo.GetAddMethod();
                Object[] addHandlerArgs = { handler };
                //var p = addHandler.GetParameters();
                addHandler.Invoke(web, addHandlerArgs);
            }
            return web;
        }
    }
```

This approach don't work as SomeOperationCompleted has `System.EventHandler <SomeOperationCompletedEventArgs>  delegate` and TestEventHandler method has `System.EventHandler <System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>` parameter type. In the same time i can just write `web.SomeOperationCompleted += TestEventHandler;`

How should i modify my code so I'll be able to subscribe to those events in my WebManager class?

Answer (score 0):

As usually, right after i post my question i'm able to answer it :)

This code works:

```
    public void TestEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // analyze web-call results here: 
        // do we have exception or web-operation completed successfully
        // if (e.Error != null) { /*do something there*/  }        
    }
    public SomeServiceReference.AuthenticationServiceClient AuthenticationService
    {
        get
        {
            var web = new SomeServiceReference.AuthenticationServiceClient();
            var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            var type = web.GetType();
            var eventsCompleted = type.GetEvents(bindingFlags).Where(e => e.Name.EndsWith("Completed")).ToArray();
            var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("TestEventHandler");
            foreach (var eventInfo in eventsCompleted)
            {
                Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this, methodInfo);
                MethodInfo addHandler = eventInfo.GetAddMethod();
                Object[] addHandlerArgs = { handler };
                addHandler.Invoke(web, addHandlerArgs);
            }
            return web;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I'm not sure what the base type is for your service reference, but is there any chance you could inherit from your service proxy and override an existing method that is always called when an async operation completes? If you can, then I would think that would be a much cleaner solution, especially since you have control over the creation of the service proxy.